# Php clock 2 hours back

Tags: php, date, time

So the clock is 18:37 right now in sweden but it prints out 16:37 why is that?

```
$timestamp = time();
date('M d, H:i', $timestamp)
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [`date.timezone`](http://www.php.net/date.timezone) setting in your `php.ini` file is incorrect. Make sure that it is set to the proper value for your timezone:

```
date.timezone = Europe/Stockholm
```

If you do not have access to the `php.ini` file, you can use [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://www.php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to set it during runtime:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm');
```

For a list of supported timezones, refer to the [PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/timezones).

---

If it still doesn't work, make sure your server is set to the proper timezone. If you've set the time manually and the timezone is incorrect (but since the time has been corrected manually it still shows the proper time), PHP has no way to get the `UTC` time properly and therefore returns the incorrect time.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, no I don't.

Comment: I'm catching up to you on the PHP stats board though.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your server is located in a time that is 2 hour back from you.

You can use this page of the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php) to fix the timezone issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try a line like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
```

Except, y'know, for Sweden.